# Unable to build new project in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, mobile, android-studio

I created a new project in Android Studio with the default activity settings. As soon as the project loads into the IDE it throws the below error message. Also I notice the layout folder with activity.xml is missing.

Error:Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at http://gradle.org/docs/2.2.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html

### Please read the following process output to find out more:

```
05:33:55.379 [main] DEBUG o.g.l.daemon.bootstrap.DaemonMain - 
Assuming the daemon was started with following jvm opts: 
[-XX:MaxPermSize=256m, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -Xmx1024m, 
-Dfile.encoding=windows-1252, -Duser.country=IN, -Duser.language=en, -Duser.variant]
```

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not create service of type DaemonContext using DaemonServices.createDaemonContext().
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Appreciate if anyone could throw light on this weird problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this
 File->Invalid caches/Restart->Invalidate caches and restart once the Android studio restarts and reloads check and see if it works.

Comment: I tried the above mentioned steps but it didn't work. Also I crosschecked both JDK and system bit version; both are 64bit but still this issue is creeping in.

Comment: what operating system are you using?

Comment: Operating System is Windows 8.1

Comment: try to "Run as Administrator"

Comment: Amazing it worked.... When I went to ProgramFiles->Android and selected the app it complained 32 bit version can't be used with 64bit JVM. I selected 64bit Android Studio and right clicked on it to run as Adminstrator and all my issues including Emulator loading is fixed. Thank You So Much!